# The correct if statement with and in this situation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this data in my database

```
 id      shift_no    time_in    time_out
 ---------------------------------------
 1       Shift 1     06:00:00   14:00:00
 2       Shift 2     14:00:00   22:00:00
 3       Shift 3     22:00:00   06:00:00
```

So I got this date:

```
convert(time(0),dateadd(HOUR, 15, getdate()), 108)
```

I want to get only the shift that is within the range of this time convert(time(0), dateadd(HOUR, 15, getdate()), 108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for an answer, but I'm not able to comment *quite* yet...this is comment for Tanner's answer.

Can you try splitting the 3rd shift entry:

```
INSERT INTO #shifts
(
    shiftNo,
    time_In,
    time_Out
)
VALUES
(1, '06:00:00', '14:00:00'),
(2, '14:00:00', '22:00:00'),
(3, '22:00:00', '23:59:59'),
(3, '00:00:00', '06:00:00');

-- the selected time
SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(HOUR, 15, GETDATE()), 108);

-- filter your shifts
SELECT *
FROM #shifts AS s
WHERE CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(HOUR, -6, GETDATE()), 108)
BETWEEN s.time_In AND s.time_Out;

DROP TABLE #shifts;
```

Comment: this could work, but depends on high tightly your source data is bound to these shifts, seems like a workaround for something that you could solve. i'll try again later

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BETWEEN` with your in and out times like so (note the below is re-runnable):

```
CREATE TABLE #shifts
(
    shiftNo INT,
    time_In TIME(0),
    time_Out TIME(0)
);

INSERT INTO #shifts
(
    shiftNo,
    time_In,
    time_Out
)
VALUES
(1, '06:00:00', '14:00:00'),
(2, '14:00:00', '22:00:00'),
(3, '22:00:00', '06:00:00');

-- the selected time
DECLARE @selectedTime TIME(0) = CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(HOUR, 12, GETDATE()), 108);

-- modify the selected time if it falls in the shift that crosses midnight
SET @selectedTime = CASE WHEN @selectedTime > '22:00:00' OR @selectedTime < '06:00:00' 
                         THEN '22:01:00' -- modified value
                         ELSE @selectedTime -- regular value
                    END;
-- show the time we are working with
SELECT @selectedTime;

-- filter your shifts
SELECT *
FROM #shifts AS s
WHERE @selectedTime
BETWEEN s.time_In AND CASE WHEN s.time_Out = '06:00:00' -- is the out time  6.00
                           THEN '23:59:59' -- change it to before midnight if so
                           ELSE s.time_Out -- keep the time as it is
                      END;

DROP TABLE #shifts;
```

The `CASE` statements in the queries work out if the times you are working with `@selectedTime` is a time that will cross over midnight before `s.time_Out` they are both adjusted, which allows the last shift to be selected.

There is probably a simpler solution, but this works with the data you have provided.

Comment: I dont know why sir but it doesnt return any value: My current time here is: 22:58:37 so it should be inside the Shift 3 but it doesnt return any value

Comment: it didnt for me though :(

Comment: @GGw you're right, the issue is that you are splitting the times, so that crosses over 1 day, which using between won't deal with

Comment: It's because the comparison doesn't account for the `BETWEEN 22:00:00 AND 06:00:00` case.

Comment: There must be something that can compare though :(

Comment: @GGw if you change the query to a smaller number than 15, the other 2 cases work. Is this the extent of your cases or are there more cases to deal with?

Comment: I added 15 hours to keep up with the time i have in my PC sir

Comment: I tried adding from 1 to 13 and it worked when i put 14 or 15 it didnt :(

Comment: those are the values that would put you in the last shift, which wouldn't work as: 23 is not between 22 and 6

Comment: haven't had a chance to revisit this, but you would need to put in logic to detect if the dateadd caused the shift to fall in to the last row, and handle it. i will try to check again later.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 

*

from yourtable

where 
time_in between getdate() and convert(time(0),dateadd(HOUR, 15, getdate()), 108)
or time_out between getdate() and convert(time(0),dateadd(HOUR, 15, getdate()), 108)
```

Comment: note that your time is returning the value 06:52:55. So not sure what you mean by 'the range of this time' so I have guessed that you mean between the time now and then.

Comment: we cant use getdate() as it returns datetime while the time i got is time(0)